# Sidebar Shifts To Bottom In Some Pages But Perfect In Other Pages

Tags: html, css

/* CSS Sidebar Wrapper */

```
#sidebar-wrapper {background:#fff;float:right;width:32%;margin:auto;border-bottom:1px solid #e9e9e9;}
.sidebar-inner {padding:20px;}
.sidebar .widget-content,.sidebar-two .widget-content {padding:20px 0;}
.sidebar h2,.sidebar-two h2,.sidebar h3,.sidebar-two h3{overflow:hidden;position:relative;font-family:&#39;Roboto Condensed&#39;;font-size:16px;font-weight:700;padding:10px 0;margin:0;text-transform:uppercase;display:block;background:#fff;border-bottom:2px solid #444;transition:All .3s ease-out}
.sidebar h2:after,.sidebar-two h2:after,.sidebar h3:after,.sidebar-two h3:after{content:&#39;&#39;;display:inline-block;position:absolute;height:14px;top:0;margin:12px 0 12px 10px;width:100%;background:url(http://4.bp.blogspot.com/-R2WTW6O9E1o/VX7dqIGT1eI/AAAAAAAACc4/pyvQDMMLX3E/s1600/repeat-bg.png)repeat}
.sidebar .widget,.sidebar-two .widget {background:#fff;margin:0 0 20px;}
.sidebar ul, .sidebar ol,.sidebar-two ul, .sidebar-two ol {list-style-type:none;margin:0;padding:0;}
.sidebar li,.sidebar-two li {margin:5px 0;padding:0;}
```

[where it is perfect](http://www.hindisongsnotes.in/2014/03/let-it-go-demi-lovato-full-song-piano.html)

Could Images Be Causing This Problem?

I Did not found any problem in the HTML But I can post if necessary. CSS Has been attached.

Answer (score 0):

[Not Perfect](http://www.hindisongsnotes.in/2016/02/sanam-re-sanam-re-title-track-arijit.html)

Link For The Page Where It Is Not Being Displayed On The Desired Position But On The Bottom Of The pAge